# Continuous map of differentiable manifolds is differentiable if differentiable functions pull back to differentiable functions

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is Exercise 3.1.A. in [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf)

> Suppose that $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map of differentiable manifolds. Show that $\pi$ is differentiable if differentialble functions pull back to differentiable functions, i.e., if pullback by $\pi$ gives mpa $\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$.

Let $f: V\subseteq Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on an open subset of $Y$. Let $(U,\phi)$ be a chart of $X$, $(V,\psi)$ be a chart of $Y$. Then $f\circ\pi(\phi^{-1})$ is differentiable and $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ is differentiable. We need to show that $\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable. I don't know how to prove this.

Can we say that since $(U,\psi\circ\pi)$ constructs a chart of $X$, by the compatibility, $\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable? This seems true but this does not use the fact that $f$ is differentiable.

Sorry I have no background of Differentiable Manifolds. Any help would be appreciated.

I also saw this post: [pullback of continuous maps of manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284679/pullback-of-continuous-maps-of-manifolds), but I don't understand how $\gamma$ is smooth in the answer. $\gamma=\beta\circ\rho$, where $\rho$ is defined to be smooth, but $\beta$ is not.

Comment: I don't change the names: the condition "$\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable for any charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$" **is** the definition of differentiable map $\pi:X\to Y$!

Comment: @Armandoj18eos: But $\pi$ is not differentiable yet. Isn't that what we need to show? Also $\psi$, $\phi$ are not differentiable. They are just homeomorphisms, right?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos: Thanks! I see! $\psi$ is differentiable since differentiable functions are defined as a function whose compositions with inverse of all charts are differentiable. I didn't realized this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a continuous map of differentiable manifolds such that
\begin{equation*}
\forall V\subseteq Y\,\text{open,}\,\pi_{*}(V):f\in\mathcal{O}_Y(V)\mapsto f\circ\pi_{|\pi^{-1}(V)}\in\mathcal{O}_X(\pi^{-1}(V));
\end{equation*}
if $(V,\psi)$ is a chart of $Y$, without loss of generality one can assume that $(\pi^{-1}(V)=U,\phi)$ is a chart of $X$.

By definition $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $\psi\circ\pi_{|U}\circ\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a continuous map; by hypothesis
\begin{equation*}
\forall f\in\mathcal{O}_Y(V),\,f\circ\pi_{|U}=(f\circ\psi^{-1})\circ(\psi\circ\pi_{|U}):U\to V\to\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
is differentiable, that is
\begin{equation*}
f\circ\pi_{|U}\circ\phi^{-1}=(f\circ\psi^{-1})\circ(\psi\circ\pi_{|U}\circ\phi^{-1}):\mathbb{R}^n\to U\to\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
is differentiable.

Passing to coordinates, for any $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ is
\begin{equation*}
f\circ\psi^{-1}:\underline{y}=(y_1,\dots,y_m)\in\mathbb{R}^m\to f\left(\psi^{-1}\left(\underline{y}\right)\right)\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation*}
in other words, $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ is a differentiable function in $m$ variables. Of course, the $y_i$'s are the (local) coordinates of $Y$ on $V$; one kows that the functions
\begin{equation*}
\psi_i\equiv pr_i\circ\psi^{-1}:(y_1,\dots,y_m)\in\mathbb{R}^m\to y_i\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
are differentiable.

The same reasoning holds for $\phi$!

By previous remark, one proves that the component functions of $\pi_{|U}$ are differentiable; by gluing axiom, $\pi$ is a differentiable map of manifolds.

Comment: In fact, we don't need $f$ here, right? If the component functions of $\psi$ are differentiable, then $\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable, which proves $\pi$ is differentiable.

Comment: No, we need of $f$; because the differentiability of $\psi_i$'s (and $\phi_j$'s) is proved using the differentiable curve on $Y$ (and $X$). Do you understand me?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this subject. But I found that the definition of a differentiable function, say $\alpha$, on a differentiable manifold $M$ is: for any chart $(U,\phi)$ on $M$, $\alpha\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable. But doesn't this imply that all charts must be differentiable since they satisfy the compatibility property? So in our case, shouldn't $\psi_j$ be automatically differentiable? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sorry for my absence; just a remark: *$\psi$ need not to be differentiable*, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601544/defining-a-differentiable-structure-by-means-of-functions/1620932#1620932)!

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how this example explains it. Could you check my argument below: I understand that the graph of the function $|\cdot|$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the standard atlas is not smooth. But it is smooth under the atlas of the projection $\psi: (x,|x|)\mapsto x$. Then if $\psi_j$ is a chart in this atlas, it is smooth by definition, since $\psi_j\circ\psi_i^{-1}=id$ on any $U_i\cap U_j$, for any $i$.

Comment: No, $\psi$ is the one coordination map! You require only that it is a homeomorphism of topological space; so you can induce a differentiable structure on the graph of $|\cdot|$ ($M$ for simplicity), and after you can prove that is differentiable with respect to differentiable structures of $M$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So when you say $\psi$ need not to be differentiable, this "differentiable" is in the normal sense, but not with respect to the differentiable structure of $M$?

Comment: Yes, it is! In general, where I write "$f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is (not) differentiable" I mean "$f$ is (not) differentiable with respect to differential structures on $M$ and $\mathbb{R}$". In the case of coordination maps, first one introduces a differential structure on the range, and after one says "it is differentiable". Is it clear?

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for your patience! One more question, in your definition of $\psi_i$, shouldn't the domain be $V\subseteq Y$?

Comment: Now I understand. I missed the point that $\psi$ is only defined on the domain of this chart. But still, was your definition of $\psi_i$ a typo?

Comment: No, it's an buse of notation, as I edited! ;)